# Why is kate sudo-ed when remote file type is unknown?

Tags: sudo, kde, kate, file-type

I am accessing a remote server in Konqueror file manager using fish:// protocol (over SSH). All known file types that are plain text I can edit in Kate directly (right click > Open with > Kate). There are files that cannot be a made "known". For instance the .bashrc file in the user home directory cannot be added to file associations and therefore always remains unknown.

When I right click I see the option "Open with ...". I can then choose kate manually, but that apparently for some reason starts "kdesudo kate" and it asks my local user password. Elevated as root user there are other or no private ssh keys and consequently I am asked for enter the remote user password, which is random and not memorised.

How do I make life easier? How to add .bashrc to file associations? Or how to avoid that kate is sudo-ed?

Comment: Edit configuration files on remote serve is usually made by command line.  For instance: do a **ssh** log in  and edit by **nano**, **vim** or similar.   Is there a good  reason you prefer to use a more advanced text editor, as kate is?

Comment: Yes, there was no other way but doing it the way you suggested, but that does not answer my question.